Revealing Refugee's Identity to Origin country's Embassy
I'm a refugee in Canada who has already acquired the PR.
I was originally a dependent under my parent's refugee application.
This same parent decided now to share their ID and all their children's identities with our origin country's embassy, hoping for monetary assistance.
Me and my siblings are all of legal age now.
My questions are:

What can be done about the parent revealing my identity to the embassy? With the possibility of them having shared my documents and passport without my consent.

What can I expect now that my identity as a refugee has been revealed?
(The country of origin is an authoritarian country with known history of non tolerance for "traitors" aka refugees.)



Re Q2, are you asking about possible repercussions in Canada or your country of origin? Or both?

Re Q1, you could try contacting an immigration lawyer or the Office of the Privacy Committee to find out if the unauthorised disclosure by your parent is covered by legislation eg Canadian privacy laws

@Traveller privacy laws generally concern commercial use of personal information, so they won't apply.  There may be some other legislation that does apply, however.

The passport was issued by the country of origin, which means they already know all the information on there once your parent shares your identity. Did the parent also share Canadian documents with the embassy?

If it was your parent who applied for refugee status, and not you, then isn't your parent the "traitor", and not you? Your parent was the one who claimed to be afraid of going back to the country to get their status; you were allowed to come as a dependent without claiming that you were afraid of going back to the country. So it seems like your parent should be the one the country might have a problem with, and not you.

I guess your country of origin could deprive you of your citizenship, although as a refugee in Canada you’d presumably not be planning to (ever) return to said country.
